# In a CASE Statement, which is faster: "WHEN [field] in (0)" or "WHEN [field] = 0"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, performance, stored-procedures, query-performance

I'm looking at a stored proc that another guy has written and every `WHEN` clause is using an `IN` statement instead of `=`.  My gut tells me this isn't as fast, efficient, etc.

For example:

```
CASE WHEN a.Indicator in ('Yes') then 'something'
     WHEN a.STATUS in (0) then 'something 0'
     WHEN a.STATUS in (1) then 'something 1'
     WHEN a.STATUS in (2) then 'something 2'
     WHEN a.STATUS in (3,4,5,6,7,8) then 'something big'
END
```

Is it faster to use `IN` instead of `=`?

Comment: Check the query plan for both, and I can just about guarantee that you'll see the same result.  It's just syntax, not semantics.

Comment: I agee with@Jon. You may get improvement in performance though, if you can convert those `CASE` clauses into joins.

Comment: @ypercube I think performance difference depends on a lot of factors - I don't think you should make a blanket statement that joins are always going to outperform constant scans (I'm assuming you're referring to a case like the above where maybe `Status` values are stored in a table - will depend on indexes, stats, size of status table, etc).

Comment: @Erik just a semantic thing - `CASE` is an expression, not a statement. Thinking about it as a statement gets people into trouble, as it implies that it can be used for control of flow (as it is in other languages like VB).

Comment: @Aaron: I was careful to use "you *may* get", not *always*. I agree with all the rest.

Comment: @ypercube yes, but if you read it a certain way you seem to imply that performance can't get worse, and it certainly could depending on the scenario. I've often removed superfluous joins to static, 5-row lookup tables and hard-coded the values in CASE instead, and it simplified the plan and improved query performance. So I'm just suggesting that moving those constants out to a join may be better, but it may be worse.

Comment: @Aaron: You are absolutely right, performance may get worse indeed. I had some really bad queries in mind, with more than 50 WHENs and nested CASE expressions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following construct:

```
c IN (x, y, z)
```

Gets extrapolated to:

```
c = x OR c = y OR c = z
```

It will logically follow that `c IN (x)` extrapolates to `c = x`. Therefore the first comment is absolutely right: you will not see a difference in performance except at the very edge case (where the size of the query text is actually impacted sufficiently by the choice), but even there it is hard to fathom the performance difference being worth mentioning.